# Linux partition end is greater than the physical disk and partition size

Tags: linux, arch-linux, filesystems, parted

I have two partitions on my hard drive. `/dev/sdb1` for my entire system and `/dev/sdb2` as a swap drive. I had a couple of system crashes and thought that I might need to increase the size of my swap drive from 2GB to 16GB. I did that by decreasing the end of `/dev/sdb1` by 14 GB (from 494GB to 480GB) using the `resizepart` command inside parted. After a reboot my system (Arch Linux) boot failed:

[image: Arch boot error]

I managed to fix the error by increasing the partition end of `/dev/sdb1` to 494GB again.
But I cannot understand why parted shows the drive capacity as 500GB and the partition end (`dev/sdb1`) of 494GB. `lsblk` and `fdisk` return a total drive size of 465.76 GB and a partition size of 460.1 GB (`/dev/sdb1`). And why is the filesystem size with 480GB bigger than the physical hard drive and with 494GB not (in relation to the error above)?

Here are my outputs from `lsblk`, `fdisk` and `parted`:

[image: lsblk, fdisk and parted outputs]

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `parted` to resize a partition is not enough, you also need to resize the filesystem on the partition you just resized (`parted` doesn't do that). You have ext4 filesystem on `/dev/sda1` so after resizing the partition with `parted` you also need to run `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda2` to resize the filesystem (running `resize2fs` without size just adjust the filesystem size to size of the underlying device). Without this you won't be able to mount the filesystem and that's why the boot failed.

The difference between sizes in `parted` and `lsblk` is the good old [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) (GB) vs. [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) (GiB) units. `lsblk` uses binary units (1 GiB is 1024 MiB), `parted` uses metric units (1 GB is 1000 MB).
500 GB is about 465.66 GiB so nothing weird happening here.